# Make animated GIF from a movie created in iMovie.app on Mac

Tags: mac, imovie, gift

I made my first little 10-second movie in iMovie 10.1.x on macOS Mojave.

Is there a way to turn this movie into an [animated GIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF#Animated_GIF)?

Comment: Consider taking a look at this and see if it's helpful: [HOWTO Convert video to animated GIF](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3446/howto-convert-video-to-animated-gif)

Comment: There is no native way to export as a GIF in iMovie. However, you may find third party applications that can import a file type iMovie can export (.mov would work), and then convert it. Check online and the App Store.

Comment: Check out this SU answer: https://superuser.com/questions/556029/how-do-i-convert-a-video-to-gif-using-ffmpeg-with-reasonable-quality

Answer (score 10):

You can do it using the Keynote app which is preinstalled on every Mac:

1. Create a basic Keynote project
2. Remove all unnecessary text elements from the first slide
3. Drag and drop your video from the Finder into your first slide
4. If needed, edit Document's size to the required size of the final gif image
5. If needed, trim video in Format->Movie tab
6. Export Using File->Export to->Animated Gif

Here is the detailed instruction: https://macmost.com/create-an-animated-gif-from-video-on-a-mac.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This is the right answer, if you are on Mac and do not want to install 3rd party app or use external website.

Comment: This doesn't work on every Mac. Maybe on newer Macs. For example Keynote 7.0.5 doesn't have the option to Export to -> Animated Gif (it only has PDF, Powerpoint, Images, HTML, Keynote 09)

Answer (score 2):

I've used [GIF Brewery 3 by Gfycat](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/gif-brewery-3-by-gfycat/id1081413713?mt=12) to create a GIF from a MOV file.

The previous link is to Mac App Store Preview, but it will also open it in the App Store. The following link is to the developer's web site: https://gfycat.com/gifbrewery

<sub>Note that I and not affiliated with the developer of the app, just an end user. Also at the time this answer was originally posted the app was free, however it is now currently $4.99 USD.</sub>